# Windows Phone 7 TextBox doesn't allow type space

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox, inputscope

I have the next XAML code:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PollAnswerRadioTextTemplate" TargetType="RadioButton">
            <StackPanel Width="400" Margin="20,5,5,30">
                <StackPanel>
                    <RadioButton 
                                 IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                                 Click="RadioButton_Click"  
                                 CommandParameter="{Binding PControlName}" 
                                 GroupName="Answer" 
                                 Width="400">

                        <RadioButton.Content>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding PAvalue}"></TextBlock>
                        </RadioButton.Content>
                    </RadioButton>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Width="400" Text="{Binding AnswerValueText}" Tag="{Binding PControlName}" AcceptsReturn="True" >
                        <TextBox.InputScope>
                            <InputScope>
                                <InputScopeName NameValue="Chat"/>
                            </InputScope>
                        </TextBox.InputScope>
                    </TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

I can't type the space after words. How I can turn off spelling auto correction in my application?

Answer (score 0):

For your second question - simply change the InputScopeName NameValue-parameter to "AddressStreet"  - that should remove autocorrection for you. Have a look at the overview over different inputscopes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh393998%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

As for your space issue, I think that should resolve itself automatically from the change in input. if not, post some of your code-behind code to give us more information to work at.

Comment: I was changed InputScopeName to "AddressStreet", but it does not work. There are no parts of code, that manipulate with textbox.